# Str replace dont seem to match certain strings

Tags: php, str-replace, string

I have a script which takes in some user input, cleans it and tries to replace the value in a string. I found that the str replace that I use cant seem to match e.g. `11 +tum`. Why is that? Can I fix it some way? Does preg replace manage it, and if so how does that look in preg replace?

Function

The script prepares the user input string for a full text query, all words are mandatory so each space is replaced with space+. But some phrases like `11 tum`need to be searchable and thus put in double quotes. The failing part is that the scirpt cant seem to match some phrases even though echoing the valus before comparison shows they are the same, e.g. `11 tum`

Code:

```
//processedQuery e.g. 'laptop 11 tum'
```

$processedQuery = str_replace(" "," +",$processedQuery);

echo processedQuery; //parses laptop +11 +tum

```
foreach($commonQuery as $value){   //$commonQuery = array("11 tum", "13 tum", "15 tum", "17 tum", "asus eee", "asus 1005","asus 1010")

    //compile : simulated query format error
    $simulatedErrorValue = str_replace(" "," +",$value);

echo simulatedErrorValue; //parses 11 +tum

    $processedQuery = str_replace($simulatedErrorValue,'"'.$value.'"',$processedQuery);

}
```

echo $processedQuery; //parses laptop +11 +tum
//exchange 11 tum for asus eee (the other commonQuery and the last echo of $processedQuery shows the correct `laptop +"asus eee"`

Comment: Could you provide an actual code sample?

Comment: `11 +tum` is a literal substring within your string, right?

Comment: Can you show me your code for the replace please

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the input to your function. I'm getting the desired result with a small modification:

```
11 +tum
laptop +"11 tum"
asus +eee
laptop +"11 tum"
```

Your error is this line:

```
$commonQuery = array("11 tum, asus eee")
```

This is an array with just 1 member.

You want to change the array to have 2 members:

```
$commonQuery = array("11 tum" , "asus eee");
```

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
$processedQuery = 'laptop 11 tum';
$processedQuery = str_replace(" "," +",$processedQuery);
$commonQuery = array("11 tum" , "asus eee");
foreach ( $commonQuery as $value ) {   //$commonQuery = array("11 tum, asus eee")
   //compile : simulated query format error
   $simulatedErrorValue = str_replace(" "," +",$value);
   echo "$simulatedErrorValue\n"; //parses 11 +tum
   $processedQuery = str_replace($simulatedErrorValue,'"'.$value.'"',$processedQuery);
   echo "$processedQuery\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: The array was simplified for clarifying the question so unfortunately the real arary is correct. The problem is somewhere else, do you have any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Joseph: Then you have to provide us the real array, because in my answer I showed you that the input is wrong. I don't have another explanation if you can't provide the real thing or more information.

Comment: @Joseph: I'm getting the same output. If you don't want to tell us more you can delete the question!? It's probably not wise to continue.

Comment: Just to make sure we are understanding eachother, do you get this output: `laptop +"11 tum"`?

Comment: I'm not allowed to tell you this because I must enter more then 3 letters in the comment but the answer is: yes.